# using bower with flask

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I am trying to install my front end dependencies using `bower install`. I have a `package.json` that specifies bower as a dependency, as well as a postInstall which should set up the bower install command.

However, my app is a Flask app and is using the custom python build pack on heroku. I want to somehow get Heroku to install dependencies using `bower install` or `npm install` whenever it is deployed, or on some command. When I try to do `heroku run bower install`, it displays this:

```
Running `bower install` attached to terminal... up, run.6980
bash: bower: command not found
```

How can I get it to install all the bower dependencies whenever it is deployed?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the distutils commands that are executed while the packages is installed. See the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/extending.html). However note that the user installing your package might not have bower (they have Python for sure).